# Can the JVM JIT specialize non-overridden methods in sub-classes?

Tags: java, performance, inheritance, optimization, jvm

Well, that title along can't get the idea across but basically what I mean is that given some method `m()` in a class `Base`, which is not overridden in some subclass `Derived`, are the JIT compilers in current JVMs<sup>1</sup> capable of "specializing"<sup>0</sup> `m()` anyway when it makes sense, or will derived who inherit and don't override `Base.m()` share the same compiled code?

This specialization makes sense, where the *derived* class defines something that makes `m()` much simpler. For example and for the purposes of discussion, let's say `m()` calls another member function `n()` and in the derived class `n()` is defined such that when `n()` is inlined into `m()` the latter is greatly simplified.

To be concrete, consider following the two non-abstract methods in the following class (which are both `m()`-type methods, while the abstract methods are the corresponding `n()` methods):

```
public class Base {

  abstract int divisor();
  abstract boolean isSomethingEnabled();

  int divide(int p) {
    return p / divisor();
  }

  Object doSomething() {
    if (isSomethingEnabled()) {
      return slowFunction();
    } else {
      return null;
  }
}
```

Both rely on abstract methods. Lets say you now have a `Derived` like this:

```
public class Derived extends Base {

  final int divisor() {
    return 2;
  }

  final boolean isSomethingEnabled() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Now the *effective* behavior of the `divide()` and `doSomething()` methods are very simply, the `divide` is not a full division by an arbitrary number, but a simply halving that can be done with bit-operations. The `doSomething()` method always returns *false*. I assume that when the `JIT` goes to compile `divide()` or `doSomething()` if `Derived` is the *only* subclass, all is good: there exists (currently) only one possible implementation for the two abstract calls, and CHA will kick in and inline the only possible implementations and all is good.

In the more general case that other derived classes exist, however, it isn't clear to me if the JVM will only compile *one*<sup>2</sup> version of the methods in `Base` with an `invokevirtual` call to the abstract methods, or if it is smart enough to say, "Hey, even though Derived doesn't override `divisor()` I should compile a version specifically for it 'cause it's going to be much simpler".

Of course, even without specialized recompilation aggressive inlining often makes it work out fine anyway (i.e., when you call `divide()` on a class that is known or even just likely to be a `Derived`, inlining is likely to give you the good implementation anyway, but, equally, there are plenty of cases where such inlining isn't done.

---

<sup>0</sup> My specializing I don't mean anything specific beyond compiling another version of the function appropriate in some restricted domain, in the same sense that say *inlining* is a form of specialization to a specific call site, or in the same way that most functions are somewhat specialized to the current context (e.g., loaded classes, assumptions about nullness, etc).

<sup>1</sup>In particular, when one says "Can the JVM blah, blah?" one is usually talking about Hotspot, and I'm also mostly in Hotspot but also whether any other JVM can do this too.

<sup>2</sup>OK sure, you might have several version of a function, for on-stack-replacement, for different compiler levels, when deoptimization occurs, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. HotSpot JVM has at most *one current, entrant* version of compiled method. This is obvious from one-to-one relationship between `Method` and `nmethod` entities in the source code. However, there can be multiple non-entrant previous versions (e.g. nmethods compiled at lower tier and OSR stubs).
2. This single compiled version is often optimized for the most common case basing on run-time profiling. For example, when during profiling of `Base.doSomething()` JIT sees that `isSomethingEnabled()` is always invoked on `Derived` instance (even if there are more subclasses), it will optimize the call for the fast case, leaving an uncommon trap for a slow one. After this optimization `doSomething()` will look like

   ```
       if (this.getClass() != Derived.class) {
           uncommon_trap();  // this causes deoptimization
       }
       return false;
   ```

3. Profile data is collected separately for each branch and for each call site. This makes possible to optimize (specialize) a part of a method for one receiver, and the other part for a different receiver.
4. If two different receivers were detected during profiling, JIT can inline both callees guarded by a type check.
5. A virtual call with more than two receivers will be compiled using vtable lookup.

To see the method profile data use `-XX:+PrintMethodData` option available in debug builds of JVM.

Comment: Thanks, I had guessed as much from `PrintCompilation` output. You can at least partly work around it simply by copy-pasting the `m()` method into `Derived` (if it wasn't `final` in `Base`), but it violates DRY. I made a small edit to clarify that there is at most one "current" version of the method, since _actual_ seems a bit strong: the previous versions of the method may all still be running simultaneously, etc - so they are quite real in the sense that their code may still be executed indefinitely (at least for long-running methods). Feel free to revert if you disagree with the wording :)

Comment: @BeeOnRope The clarification makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, my understanding is that the JVM would not specialize a method on its own but rather optimize the base class function if it finds during profile optimization that divisor() often resolves to a certain method.

Have you tried to print from diagnostics to see what happens?

> Rather than trying to guess what the JIT is doing, you can take a peek
>   at what’s happening by turning on java command line flags:
>   -XX:+PrintCompilation -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintInlining (from [Java JIT compiler inlining](https://techblug.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/java-jit-compiler-inlining/))

Comment: I haven't seen any evidence yet from `-XX:+PrintCompilation` that this occurs, although I suppose it could be hidden. That said, I haven't looked into it deeply on more recent JVMs (and not at all on Java 9 JVMs).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [OpenJDK Wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PerformanceTechniques):

> - Methods are often inlined. This increases the compiler's "horizon" of optimization.
> - Static, private, final, and/or "special" invocations are easy to inline.
> - Virtual (and interface) invocations are often demoted to "special" invocations, if the class hierarchy permits it. A dependency is registered in case further class loading spoils things.
> - Virtual (and interface) invocations with a lopsided type profile are compiled with an optimistic check in favor of the historically common type (or two types).

That is, for the two most frequent receiver types, the derived methods would be inlined into their caller (if small enough, which should be the case here), and unreachable branches pruned.

Also, if the base method is small enough for inlining into its caller, it will be optimized for that caller's two most frequent receiver types.

That is, the Hotspot JVM specializes code if it is small enough for inlining for the two most frequent receiver types of that call site.

Comment: Yeah, I know about that and I kind of tried to cover it in the last paragraph - inlining often makes this "just work", particularly when the whole base method gets inlined (since then you really can prune everything about the `n()`-type methods away). I don't think the conditional inlining (aka "inline caches") is as powerful as true inlining though - the fallback code for other types (if any exist) can't really be pruned away - it has to be present either as a stub which triggers deoptimization, or actually present. This inhibits other optimizations throughout the function.

Comment: Then the other problem is that this is based on inlining the _at the call site of the `m()` method_, whereas the important optimization (for the purposes of this question) is at the call site of `n()` inside `m()`. The "inlineability" of the former doesn't necessarily have a relationship with the latter. To be specific, imagine that `m()` is too large to be inlined or that at the call-site of `m()` there are too many receiver types to inline it: in that case it may still be highly useful to inline `n()` into `m()`.

Answer (score -1):

The JVM doesn't define nor redefine types. It interprets running implementations of behaviors. It's the compiler, i.e., the source language that deals in types. The JVM is the low level, the "metal" of the Java universe. Types and their instances are instructions to create a series of observable events influenced by inputs. That series of inputs and observable events over time constitute what computer scientists call the "semantics" of a program.

It's up to the JVM to figure out ways to carry out those instructions while preserving the semantics. It will, at times, destroy a class structure entirely, in effect. Conceptually a class instance lives in heap memory with labeled attributes. For some period of time, until the semantics prohibit it because of some state change, the JVM might keep two active values in registers, not even in RAM, and ignore the whole rest of the defined class. Is that "specializing" the method?

No, it is not. There is no new definition, no new set of Java-level instructions, no ephemeral type in the JVM. There's just a temporary, compiled and optimized way in the moment to fulfill the instructions. When the optimization no longer works, or matters as much, the JVM even reverts to interpreting bytecode. And bytecode won't contain any new types, either. It's an assembly language, and redefining what the high-level code demands is above its pay grade.

Bottom line, the only types in the program are those mandated in the source code, not the bytecode or JVM. All the semantics come from the source.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I understand very well the restrictions placed on the JVM by the JLS and the JVMS, and many of the ways that it optimizes in practice - but my question is: _do any current JVMs apply the specific optimization described above_. So to be clear, when I say "Can the JVM ..." here, the _can_ is to be interpreted as "Are the current implementations capable of ..." not "Is it allowed by the spec to ...". Granted, that's not clear by the title alone, but I think explained myself well in the text.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand your question. And what you described is not an optimization. What I explained is that the JVM doesn't deal in types. Your question is not applicable to the JVM. There isn't a concept of classes sharing a method, there's a concept of creating the current execution in accordance with the semantics. I guess that doesn't preclude different classes' instances from sharing some optimized piece, so to speak, but at that level it's a metaphor at best to say that. Instead of accusing someone else of misunderstanding, at least consider the alternative.

Comment: Of course what I described is an optimization, just like a million other things like inlining, class hierarchy analysis, etc. It is invisible to the end user and doesn't affect the semantics. Almost your entire answer is a non-sequitur, off in the weeds explaining things I never asked about and have no bearing on the question. _Misunderstanding_ was a charitable interpretation, the other one is that your answer doesn't make a lot of sense. You seem to have fixated on the word "specializing" and answered the question for some specific meaning of that word that I never intended.

Comment: In any case, I tried to clarify a bit in my intro not to read too much into "specializing" and to take this as a simple question about whether this optimization is _performed_ (whether it is _allowed_ is not really up for debate - it is allowed).

Comment: I don't think it's a meaningful question. Similar code might be optimized similarly, is my best guess. You won't have the concept of "classes share a refactored method" in the JVM at that level.